# Slider w/ controls bind to select

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have put together a jQuery UI range slider with controls, although I am trying to bind it also to a `select` so that choosing a value from dropdown moves slider and moving with controls changes value in select dropdown

```
var gmin = 0;
var gmax = 500;
var s =  $("#slider").slider({
    value: 0,
    min: gmin,
    max: gmax,
    step: 100,
    slide: function(event, ui) {
        $("#select option").val(ui.value);
    }
});

$('#up').click(function() {       
    s.slider('value', s.slider('value') + s.slider("option", "step"));   
});

$('#down').click(function() {
    s.slider('value', s.slider('value') - s.slider("option", "step"));   
});
```

Problems at the moment:

- up-down buttons change select values to one value only
- choosing a value from dropdown select does not move slider aswell.

Any tips here as I am lacking a bit of knowledge unfortunately.

FIDDLE: http://jsfiddle.net/nrNX8/517/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue with the `select` is because you need to set the `val()` of the `select` itself, no the `text()` of all the `option` elements within it.

Then you can hook to the `change` event of the `select` to update the slider with the chosen value, something like this:

```
$('#up').click(function() {
    s.slider('value', s.slider('value') + s.slider("option", "step"));
    $('#select').val(s.slider('value'));
});

$('#down').click(function() {
    s.slider('value', s.slider('value') - s.slider("option", "step"));
    $('#select').val(s.slider('value'));
});

$('#select').change(function() {
    s.slider('value', $(this).val());
});
```

[**Updated fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/RoryMcCrossan/nrNX8/520/)

Comment: No problem, glad to help

Answer (score 0):

Add this block of code on the `change` event of select element.

```js
$("#select").change(function(e){
      s.slider('value',  e.target.value);   

});
```